# how to write nested objects to flat file with FFpojo in java

Tags: java, flat-file

I have 5 custom objects inside an object(`fmtsI`). I want to  write `fmtsi` object to flat file. How to allocate the positions for the fields of customs objects and write it to file?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try anything. Show us your code. Consider serializing to Json and write that string to the file.

Comment: it's not writing object to file directly, fields are having variable lengths, if the value is less than the specified length, have to append space. So, I chose the FFpojo. i am asking approach, whether ffpojo has anything to deal with nested objects.

Comment: I only see 6 question that mention ffpojo on stackoverflow. Makes me think it is probably the wrong choice.

Comment: @bhspencer, thanks for responding. I came up with writing a method in custom objects to return the string as needed and use it in the primary object.